# exponential squared

Tags: exponential-function

I have the following equation

$$v=ac\exp(-ct)$$

If I square this equation, is the following correct?

$$v^2 = a^2c^2\exp(-ct)*\exp(-ct) = a^2c^2\exp(-2ct)$$

This result is because:

$$e^{(x+y)} = e^xe^y$$

"e" and "exp" are the same thing.

Comment: That is correct

Comment: Thanks.  I edited the equation.  The first equation should have had a coefficient of "ac" and not "a".

Comment: Also, $(e^x)^2=e^{2x}$.. no need for $\text{exp}(-ct)*\text{exp}(-ct)$..